# Is there a way to insert a js variable into json payload?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to set two variables "TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES" "GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS" and then insert them into the json payload for a slack webhook following https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/webhook. I am completely inexperienced with js/nodejs so please understand if I'm making a simple mistake

I have tried setting the variables at the top of the .js script and tried escaping/unescaping the values but I'm having trouble

```
const IncomingWebhook = require('@slack/webhook').IncomingWebhook;
const url = process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL;
const webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url);
var x = "10"
const TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES = "10"
const GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS = "90"

// Send the notification
if (x == "10")
(async () => {
  await webhook.send({
    text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
    attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS*"}}]}]
  });
})();

else {console.log("What's up");}
```

I would expect the webhook to return 10 and 90 in place of TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES and GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS but it is returning the literal string

EDIT: I've used the string concatenation posted below and it served my purpose and kept my payload more modular, thank you very much for all the help

`text: "@here *" + TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES + "* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *" + GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS + "*"`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar need backticks not quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `` ( [**Template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) )

```
text: `@here *${TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES}* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *${GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS}*`
```

Or you can use string concatination too

```
text: "@here *" + TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES + "* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *" + GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS + "*"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use string interpolation feature of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Syntax is:

`string text ${expression} string text`.

In your case you could

```
`text: "@here *${TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES}"`
```